# Is `/usr/lib/binfmt-support/run-detectors` supposed to choose mono or wine to run a windows or .net executable?

Tags: ubuntu, wine, binfmt

On Lubuntu 18.04, Is `/usr/lib/binfmt-support/run-detectors`   supposed to choose mono or wine to run a windows or .net executable?

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/cli 
enabled
interpreter /usr/lib/binfmt-support/run-detectors
flags: 
offset 0
magic 4d5a

$ file /usr/lib/binfmt-support/run-detectors
/usr/lib/binfmt-support/run-detectors: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=06509e829163c8e50781b5335883bf9a8ed47321, stripped
```

Why can't I run a Windows executable? How can I make `run-detectors` work?

```
$ ./PDFXCview.exe 
run-detectors: unable to find an interpreter for ./PDFXCview.exe
$ file ./PDFXCview.exe 
./PDFXCview.exe: PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows

$ type wine
wine is /usr/bin/wine
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is `/usr/lib/binfmt-support/run-detectors ./PDFXCview.exe` working or failed with "run-detectors: unable to find an interpreter for ./PDFXCview.exe" again?

Comment: If that failed again, please make sure you install mono and wine correctly and they are both in your PATH. Or simply make sure your exe is really working on Windows (not corrupted file).

Comment: Also see https://superuser.com/questions/180112/why-is-ubuntu-trying-to-open-my-mono-app-with-wine-instead-of-mono/180226